# ¿Hay alguna manera de crear arreglos dinámicos cuyos elementos sean de distinta clase en c++ similares a los de python?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

El principal problema es que necesito modificar el tipo del puntero a puntero `matrix` para así poder modificar el resto del arreglo de arreglo. Pero no sé cómo modificar ese puntero para que sea de otro tipo de dato, diferente al inicial, dado que el tipo de dato del `template` se define al ser definido el array, y se debe hacer dentro de la misma clase del arreglo en `setAll`, la cual cambia el tipo de dato de cada celda de la matriz.

O sea que mi pregunta es cómo modifico el puntero `matrix` de tal forma que, por ejemplo, al ser definido como `int` cambie a por ejemplo `float`, para poder modificar el arreglo para que contenga puros elementos de tipo `float`.

```
 class DynamicMatrix {
  private:
    int rows;
    int columns;
    E **matrix;
    void checkIndexes(int rows, int columns);
  public:
    DynamicMatrix(int rows, int columns);
    ~DynamicMatrix();

    E getValue(int row, int column);
    void setValue(int row, int column, E element);

    int getRows();
    int getColumns();

    void setAll(E element);

    void transpose();

    void addRow(E element);
    void addColumn(E element);

    void removeRow(int row);
    void removeColumn(int column);

    void print();
};

template <typename E>
DynamicMatrix<E>::DynamicMatrix(int rows, int columns) {
  if (rows <= 0 || columns <= 0) {
    throw runtime_error("Invalid number of rows or columns.");
  }
    this->rows = rows;
    this->columns = columns;
    matrix = new E*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      matrix[i] = new E[columns];
    }
}

template <typename E>
void DynamicMatrix<E>::setAll(E element) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      matrix[i] = new E[columns];
    }
  for (int row = 0; row < getRows(); row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < getColumns(); column++) {
      setValue(row, column, element);
    }
  }
}
~~~

~~~
int main(){
    DynamicMatrix<int> m(8, 10);
   // srand(time(0));

    /*for (int r = 0; r < m.getRows(); r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < m.getColumns(); c++) {
            m.setValue(r, c, rand() % 100);
        }
    }*/
    m.setAll('h');
    m.print();

    return 0;
}
~~~
```

Comment: ¿ Versión de C++ ? ¿ 98, 11, 14, 17 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias tener una tupla para encapsular a arreglos dinamicos de distintos tipos

ejemplo:

```
#include <tuple> //para trabajar con tuplas
#include <vector> // para trabajos con arreglos dinamicos

std::tuple<vector<TIPO_DATO>,vector<TIPO_DATO>) <nombre_variable>
```

creo que eso te serviria...

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Hay alguna manera de crear arreglos dinámicos cuyos elementos sean de distinta clase en C++?

No… y si, **pero**…

---

Puedes tener una colección de punteros a clases que dispongan de una base común:

```
#define P void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

struct Base{ virtual void f() = 0; };
struct D1 : public Base{P};
struct D2 : public Base{P};
struct D3 : public Base{P};
struct D4 : public Base{P};

int main()
{
    auto b = new Base*[4]{new D1, new D2, new D3, new D4};

    for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
        b[i]->f();

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> virtual void D1::f()
> virtual void D2::f()
> virtual void D3::f()
> virtual void D4::f()
> ```

Pero no es un buen código, se desaconseja el uso de punteros en crudo en C++ moderno, mejor usar punteros inteligentes:

```
#define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct Base{ virtual void f() = 0; virtual ~Base() = default; };
struct D1 : public Base { void f() {P;} ~D1() {P;}};
struct D2 : public Base { void f() {P;} ~D2() {P;}};
struct D3 : public Base { void f() {P;} ~D3() {P;}};
struct D4 : public Base { void f() {P;} ~D4() {P;}};

int main()
{
    using b_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
    b_ptr b[4]{b_ptr{new D1}, b_ptr{new D2}, b_ptr{new D3}, b_ptr{new D4}};

    for (auto &d : b)
        d->f();

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> virtual void D1::f()
> virtual void D2::f()
> virtual void D3::f()
> virtual void D4::f()
> virtual D4::~D4()
> virtual D3::~D3()
> virtual D2::~D2()
> virtual D1::~D1()
> ```

Las últimas tendencias de C++ no aconsejan esta aproximación tampoco, podrías usar en su lugar una `std::variant`:

```
#define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct D1 { void f() {P;} ~D1() {P;}};
struct D2 { void f() {P;} ~D2() {P;}};
struct D3 { void f() {P;} ~D3() {P;}};
struct D4 { void f() {P;} ~D4() {P;}};

int main()
{
    using d_variant = std::variant<D1, D2, D3, D4>;
    d_variant v[4]{D1{}, D2{}, D3{}, D4{}};

    for (auto &d : v)
        std::visit([](auto &x) { x.f(); }, d);

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> D1::~D1()
> D2::~D2()
> D3::~D3()
> D4::~D4()
> void D1::f()
> void D2::f()
> void D3::f()
> void D4::f()
> D4::~D4()
> D3::~D3()
> D2::~D2()
> D1::~D1()
> ```

Tendrás que valorar qué solución se ajusta mejor a tus necesidades.